# Proper ukulele strumming technique

Tags: ukulele, strumming

I've browsed the internet and found a few different techniques mentioned. Generally, they involve either the index finger, thumb, or multiple fingers.

Are all these techniques correct and just used in different contexts? As a beginner, is there one I should prefer?

Comment: What actually makes a technique *correct*..?

Comment: In some cases, you can make efficiency arguments, like one chord fingering is easier than another. For strumming techniques, I guess it'd be more like what sound people expect from a ukulele. But I could imagine someone using just their pinky or a guitar pick. Not sure if that's incorrect or weird.

Comment: It makes it *different*. And in some cases, *better*, not particularly incorrect or weird, so why don't players develop their own ways. Most of us did with handwriting, for instance...

Answer (score 2):

Different strumming techniques make different sounds. When I was first beginning on the uke, I used my thumb to strum while I was still figuring out how to make the chords. I  soon switched to my index finger (nail pointed down) and found this a little easier to play while making a bigger sound. I still use my thumb occasionally when I want a mellower sound.

There are many other strumming techniques, and they all sound different. As you progress on the uke, try working on some other strums and see what sounds you can make. The song I am working on now uses four different strums over the course of the song.

Answer (score 0):

Those are all used.  I actually either use my middle finger or a felt plectrum (which gives more sound).  Basically, you have to experiment and find out which one works best for you.

Comment: Thumb is softer sounding  than the fingers (as the latter use fingernails to strike the strings).